# How can I make sure about the order of the loaded packages?

Tags: bibliographies, packages

I have a references.bib file, however when I load the paper, I get only one reference in my bibliography list, the other few ones I tried to cite using \cite appear with "?" although the name is cited correctly.

I am aware that this problem has to do with my loaded packages and maybe their sequence. I think part of the error comes from there. For now, I care about having a complete list more than the style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Required package
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{geometry}



\begin{document} 

\subsection{A}

 \cite{Dustmann_1996}.
 \cite{Kuhlenkasper_2012}.

\section{A}



\begin{document} 
    \bibliography{references.bib} 
    \bibliographystyle{apacite}
\end{document}

\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Tabulation of x information}
\label{Tabulation of x information}

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The last \bibliography part appears with errors, e.g.:
Citation `Kuhlenkasper_2012' undefined on input line 27.
\bibliography{references.bib} runaway argument?
l.33 \begin{document} can only used in the preamble

---

This is my references.bib (contains other references too)

```
@TECHREPORT{Kuhlenkasper_2012,
title = {Who Leaves and When?: Selective Outmigration of Immigrants from Germany},
author = {Kuhlenkasper, Torben and Steinhardt, Max},
year = {2012},
institution = {DIW Berlin, The German Socio-Economic Panel (SOEP)},
type = {SOEPpapers on Multidisciplinary Panel Data Research},
number = {490},
url = {https://EconPapers.repec.org/RePEc:diw:diwsop:diw_sp490}
}

@article{Dustmann_1996,
 DOI= {10.2307/1344525},
 ISSN = {02664658, 14680327},
 URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/1344525},
 author = {Christian Dustmann and Samuel Bentolila and Riccardo Faini},
 journal = {Economic Policy},
 number = {22},
 pages = {213--250},
 publisher = {[Center for Economic Studies, Maison des Sciences de l’Homme, Centre for Economic Policy Research, Wiley]},
 title = {Return Migration: The European Experience},
 urldate = {2022-07-31},
 volume = {11},
 year = {1996}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make sure you example can be tested by others by just coying your code. Additionally it is best with some sample bibtex data as well.

Comment: I'm not away of any loading errors that affect bibliography from the preamble you provide. Please elaborate.

Comment: Usually you put the `\bibliographystyle` first and the `\bibliography` after that, but that is probably not causing the problem. Generally when some references work but others don't then you forgot to run BibTeX again (you need to run this every time that you add some references if you want them to appear in the pdf), or you did run BibTeX again but there were some errors in the `.bib` file that prevented the bibliography from being updated. If you got errors (shown in your editor and in the `.blg` file) then please post them here together with the `.bib` entries that caused the error.

Comment: getting ? for a citation is rather unlikely to be related to the packages loaded or their order. in 999 times out of 1000 it is just a failure to run bibtex (or getting an error in bibtex so a failure to get a generated bibliography) If you want help with an error _show the error message_, just saying "appears with errors" and not providing any code that produces the error means no one can debug this

Comment: Your tex code doesn't make sense.  It has two `\begin{document}`, and then two `\end{document}`.

Comment: I always add geometry first, and it redefines several distances used by many other packages.

Comment: @JohnKormylo you mean adding it after {inputenc}?

Comment: @Marijn many thanks. I follow your package installation technique, in-cite worked for few references and then it stopped working; I no longer even get the drop-down list for the references in history when I type \cite, this used to appear before and I was selecting from it. I use \nocite{*} now to get around it.

Comment: @she I'm not sure I understand your comment. Are you unable to add any new citations to your document, i.e., do you get [?] again? Or is the problem just that the drop-down list does not appear? This drop-down list is a feature of your editor, it has nothing to do with LaTeX compilation itself. If that list stops working you should still be able to type the cite key manually inside of a `\cite` command and get a working citation out of it.

Comment: Yes, the frop-down list does not appear but also when I type the correct citation as listed in my bib, I get it not correctly cited ( it appears exactly as inside the cite curly brackets). E.g. \cite{A.2002} appears A.2002 in the text and does not show in the reference list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two main issues in the code (apart from some problems with making the MWE, like the two `\begin{document}` statements and such).

The first is the use of the `ulem` package for underlining. By default this package redefines `\emph` (a command used to give emphasis to the argument, by default in italics) to produce underlines. Apacite uses `\emph` in the bibliography which leads to an error. This can be fixed by using the `normalem` package option for `ulem`, i.e., delete `\usepackage{ulem}` and add `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`.

The second issue is that Apacite does not recognize `url` in `@techreport` (it does for `@article`). Therefore url formatting is not applied to the web address in the `Kuhlenkasper_2012` entry. Because that url contains `_` another error appears. To fix this you can use `howpublished = {\url{...}}`. This requires `\usepackage{url}`.

Another small improvement is an extra set of braces around `E` in `The {E}uropean Experience` to prevent automatic lowercasing.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Required package
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document} 

\subsection{A}

 \cite{Dustmann_1996}.
 \cite{Kuhlenkasper_2012}.

\section{A}

\bibliography{references.bib} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Tabulation of x information}
\label{Tabulation of x information}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

```
@TECHREPORT{Kuhlenkasper_2012,
title = {Who Leaves and When?: Selective Outmigration of Immigrants from Germany},
author = {Kuhlenkasper, Torben and Steinhardt, Max},
year = {2012},
institution = {DIW Berlin, The German Socio-Economic Panel (SOEP)},
type = {SOEPpapers on Multidisciplinary Panel Data Research},
number = {490},
howpublished = {\url{https://EconPapers.repec.org/RePEc:diw:diwsop:diw_sp490}}
}

@article{Dustmann_1996,
 DOI= {10.2307/1344525},
 ISSN = {02664658, 14680327},
 URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/1344525},
 author = {Christian Dustmann and Samuel Bentolila and Riccardo Faini},
 journal = {Economic Policy},
 number = {22},
 pages = {213--250},
 publisher = {[Center for Economic Studies, Maison des Sciences de l’Homme, Centre for Economic Policy Research, Wiley]},
 title = {Return Migration: The {E}uropean Experience},
 urldate = {2022-07-31},
 volume = {11},
 year = {1996}
}
```

Result:

[image]